# display json data to view laravel

Tags: jquery, json, laravel-4

my json responce is

```
0: {id:3, product_price:91, product_quantity:3, count_product:1}
1: {id:2, product_price:10, product_quantity:13, count_product:1}
```

my jquery

```
$.get('items/', {'id': itemIds}, function (obj) {

                                console.log(obj);
                                 $.each(obj, function(i, item) {
                                 // console.log(item);
                                      console.log(this.product_quantity);
                                    });
                                    //alert(ic);
                            });
```

my controller code

```
echo json_encode($ccoun);
```

here each not working any help

Comment: Have you tried change this `console.log(this.product_quantity);` to this `console.log(item.product_quantity);` ?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '136' in 1[{"id":3,"product_price":91,"product_quantity":3,"count_product":1},{"id":2,"product_price":10,"product_quantity":16,"count_product":1}]

Comment: Your json obj should be like this: `var obj = [{id:3, product_price:91, product_quantity:3, count_product:1}
, {id:2, product_price:10, product_quantity:13, count_product:1}];`

Comment: The json you give is what you get from your ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your JS function to:

```
    $.get('items/', {'id': itemIds}, function (obj) {
        console.log(obj);
        $.each(obj, function(i, item) {
            // console.log(item);
            console.log(this.product_quantity);
        });
        //alert(ic);
    }, 'json');
```

The only thing I changed is the last `json`.

EXTRA: for some reason, my old server didn't support `$.get();`, so I had to switch to `$.ajax();`. This might also help you in fixing it.